# Error al ejecutar login Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda. Al ejecutar mi código me aparece el siguiente error. **Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aitasc\assignstudent.php on line 194**
Esta es la parte del código en donde me salta el error.

```
$existeUser = "SELECT usuario FROM bdaita WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $existeUser);
$existe = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Lo que trato de hacer es un logueo de Usuario. Acá el código completo.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'database_config.php';

    $usuario     = $_POST['usuario'];
    $nombre      = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidop   = $_POST['apellidop'];
    $apellidom   = $_POST['apellidom'];
    $telefono    = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];
    $contra      = $_POST['contra'];
    $conficontra = $_POST['conficontra'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (usuario, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, telefono, email, contra, conficontra)
VALUES ('$usuario', '$nombre', '$apellidop', '$apellidom', '$telefono', '$email', '$contra', '$conficontra')";


$existeUser = "SELECT usuario FROM bdaita WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $existeUser);
$existe = mysqli_num_rows($query);



    if ($conn->query($sql) === true and $existe === 0) {
        print '
<div align = "center" class="alert info">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <strong>Excelente!</strong> Usuario Registrado Correctamente!.
</div>


<!--Script para cerrar el mensaje emergente -->
<script>
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function(){
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
    }
}
</script>
';

    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        print '
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block" style="text-align: center;">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <strong>Error!</strong> El Usuario ya existe, intente con otro!.
</div>


<!--Script para cerrar el mensaje emergente -->
<script>
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function(){
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
    }
}
</script>
';
    }

    $conn->close();

}
?>
```

Comment: `$query` es un booleano (`FALSE` probablemente debido a que la consulta falló). Puedes probar la consulta haciendo algo así: `if ( $query = mysqli_query($conn, $existeUser) )  { //aquí leer los datos }  else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));  }` Doy por supuesto que compruebas que la conexión es válida.

Comment: De hecho la consulta se hace correctamente pero el error me sigue apareciendo. ya que al isertar un nuevo usuario, el sistema manda la alerta de Usuario existente.